# Rails 4 : Geocoder with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, geocoding, rails-geocoder

When current user creates a post want to know user location via IP reverse method in Geo-coder.For that i have created a post ,user and location model. I have gone through railscasts and have learn to installed Geocoder and able to find latitude, longitude via address. Now how to integrate user id from devise to geocoder to determine current user location.

```html
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 geocoded_by :address
 after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
end


class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    #location = request.location
    @locations = Location.all
    respond_with(@locations)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@location)
  end

  def new
    @location = Location.new
    respond_with(@location)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    if params[:location].blank?
      @location = request.location
      @locations = Location.near([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude], 50, :order => :distance)
    end
    respond_with(@location)
  end
```

Updated:

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150507160846) do

  create_table "locations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "user_id"
    t.string   "integer"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "post"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "tag_list"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "location"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :locations
end
```

Comment: you can use Geocoder.search("1 Twins Way, Minneapolis")....
Geocoder.search("44.981667,-93.27833")....
Geocoder.search("204.57.220.1").....

Comment: @Milind any way to attach Geocoder to user id ??

Comment: What do you want to do....if you really want to attach user_id ,then you could have added address column to user table ...in this way every user would have its own details.But as of now..you cannot attach geocode details to user_id without making changes in model implementation....

Comment: I don't see anything in here about the blog posts either. I would expect that you would have a Pots model with a user_id column and a location column for the information from Geocoder.

Comment: @EmilKampp i have updated Schema to show all the three models.

Comment: @Milind  i have added location(address) column to user table ,but is there a way i can get user location with out asking them to enter their location.

Comment: @akhilranjith...i really dont understand..if you have address in users table..then what is the problem..you need atlest a key to query with the table to get the address....

Comment: @Milind ok , can you tell me how to get current user ip and convert to address

Comment: @akhilranjith.. i have added an answer ....hope that might help for what you are looking for... :)

Comment: @Milind Thank you for your replay ... i am going to try it !!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion ,if You want to get the users `ip` and then use it to get the `address`...you can use the below code in `user.rb` with `ip` already present in `users` table.

***Devise stores the current and last ip address of the user automagically in user table. The column names it uses are "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip".***

**Given a User model with known IP address, automatically fetch coordinates and store in latitude and longitude attributes:**

```
# app/models/user.rb
geocoded_by :current_sign_in_ip,
  :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon
after_validation :geocode
```

Comment: I am new to rails , I have created only user model and views ,no controllers ,when i checked Configuring controllers in devise github ... should i do that or so-thing else ..can you help me out with steps of instruction how to go about it..... I have also read " The location method is vulnerable to trivial IP address spoofing via HTTP headers." .So using geocoderv is it safe to get the ip from current user to find their location ???

Comment: First of all implement the default behaviour of devise by logging the user using sessions controller or registering the user first and then verify you db record.you will get the current ip hick you can use further.try it out .Or Tell me at what point you are stuck.